# Coding a python module for plotting graphs in commandline but no values are inserted into the graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, graph, command-line

I've recently picked up python and am fiddling with small projects to get first experiences. For this I want to implement a module that can take values from a tuple and plot them out on the commandline.

My approach is this:
I calculate the range of values I need to express and then divide it by the number of lines I want my graph to be long to get the steps i put my values in. Then I just iterate through all the values and check in which of these steps it lies.

My problem is, that i get no x'es in any field, except for the min_value.

Here's my code:

```
## Calculate where datapoints should go and put them there
#
range_data = max_data - min_data
steps = range_data / y_length - 1

for dat in data:
   for i in range(1, y_length):
      if dat == min_data:
         graph[data.index(dat) + 1][i] = 'x'
      if dat >= i * steps + min_data and dat <= (i + 1) * steps + min_data:
         graph[data.index(dat) + 1][i - 1] = 'x'
```

I appreciate any suggestions :)

Edit: 
Here's how my graph gets instantiated

```
graph = [[' ' for w in range(0, y_length)] for l in range(0, x_length)
```

And the min_data and max_data values are just variables for pythons min() and max() functions.

The input would be a tuple of int or float values, currently I have just hardcoded (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). This is what the output currently looks like, theres just the x for the first value, but none else:

```
10...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦...............................
¦x..............................
1------------------------------>
```

Comment: You should provide a mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve For example the current version of your question does not show how `graph` , `max_data`  and `min_data` are created. I have no idea what is  the data type of these variables

Comment: Im sorry, I added the information, aswell as my improvements so far, but I've not made a lot of progess

Comment: Please also include some sample input data as well. Also, a sample expected output (what you want to appear even though your code isn't working) would be really helpful.

Comment: I've added the current output, with the values I put in, there should be a line of x'ses nearing the upper right corner

Comment: If your input is `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`, how would you interpret it? You consider 5 points, like (1, 2), (3, 4), ..., (9, 10)?